# Does matter in the outside universe affect Hawking radiation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, black-holes, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Is there a way to modify the event horizon to make it generate other particles by affecting quantum fields outside with a giant charge increasing quantum foam disruptions affecting the radiation? Is it possible to get charged particles from this process?

Comment: Hawking radiation emits all sorts of particles. This question is unclear

Comment: What if you put something outside the black hole and influence the quantum fields outside with some other object like a giant charge and this charge would affect the electromagnetic field, so then the Hawking Radiation would be affected by this right so it may use the other fields more?

Comment: Given that the particle spectrum is affected by the charge and spin of the black hole, and is indeed non-isotropic for spin-carrying particles, not to mention superradiance effects if there are mirroring, it seems reasonable that the surroundings can affect the spectrum.

Comment: So if that is the case, would it be possible to utilize this to create a specific set of particles out of the Hawking Radiation or to influence it in such a way to get extra protons or electrons in order to use it to build something or to get extra antimatter?

Comment: This PBS Space Time video may be of interest - [Hawking Radiation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qPKj0YnKANw). $2$ and a half minutes in, it displays a list of other videos that may give more background. You can google them. E.G. the first is [Absolute Cold](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvgZqGxF3eo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hawking radiation emits all sorts of particles, including charged particles. Adding a big charge to the outside of the black hole would not alter, in principle, the particles emitted by the black hole, although it could alter their distribution: if the charge is positive, then electrons, for example, would be attracted to it while positrons would be repelled.

Nevertheless, there is a separate effect that may come into play if the electromagnetic field is strong enough: the Schwinger effect. The [Schwinger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_effect) is a different particle creation effect similar to the Hawking effect in which the presence of a strong enough electromagnetic field creates particle-antiparticle pairs out of the vacuum. I suppose a big enough charge could induce such a strong electromagnetic field so that the Schwinger effect becomes relevant and other particles are "pulled out" of the vacuum.

Comment: So in theory if there is a huge metal object and I just throw a bunch of positive charges at it and make it positive and create a huge electric field, then the effect will be similar to Hawking Radiation if hovering above the object where the electric field weakens and particles are created. So are two particles created from the electric field, and then once falls in and the other escapes then right if the object also has a gravitational field that is comparable to the Earth.

Comment: @MiltonTheMeme I can't tell how large the gravitational field of the charge would be. Yes, the effect would resemble (but definitely not equal) the Hawking effect, but it would only create charged particles. Furthermore, positive particles would be repelled from the object while negative charges would be attracted toward it, so the object would eventually discharge.